# Change Account Used With Firebase Invites

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-invites

I've implemented Firebase Invites as described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android) and it works fine.

I've discovered that if a user has multiple Google accounts then the first time the Intent is invoked, Firebase asks the user to select one of these accounts (if they choose to send an invite via email, the selected account is the one it comes from).

However, my users have complained that that there is no way to change the account that is used. Uninstalling the app and reinstalling does not cause the prompt again, so apparently Firebase is storing the selection internally.

I've found the [setAccount method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.html#setAccount(android.accounts.Account)), but that would require me to launch the account-chooser dialog and specify the Account every time. I was hoping there would be some mechanism to cause Firebase to reset the choice that it has stored internally. Is there a way to do that?

Note that calling FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() has no effect. In fact, calling FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returns null. That seems to confirm that Firebase Invites is not using Firebase Auth. [It would be nice if Google documented what is going on, instead of us having to guess how it works.]

Comment: Did you implement a sign-out option? I think what's happening is the token of the signed-in user was not revoked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work. I've updated the original question to reflect additional experimentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the private response I got from a Google engineer:

> No, there's no way to clear the default account. As they mentioned, setAccount would be the recommended way to choose the account. For this case, though, you might want to tell them that the user actually can change the account from the Invites screen by tapping on the user avatar. If they have more than one account on the device, this should bring up the account chooser to change what account emails are sent from.